# Find all the id numbers in both arrays

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find all the times the same ID is in both arrays, using the `&` comparison. When I output the arrays, you can see that there are matches, but when I try to run through them, it throws the error `no implicit conversion of nil into Array`.

```
> @fluent_user_ids
 => [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 12, 165, 166, 171, 174, 176, 177, 142, 206, 207, 208, 209, 214, 215, 216, 10, 229, 230, 232, 234, 236, 237, 238, 233, 233, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 273, 274, 276, 233] 

 > @nonfluent_user_ids
 => [2, 5, 11, 166, 142, 13, 206, 207, 208, 209, 214, 215, 216, 171, 10, 229, 230, 231, 232, 234, 236, 237, 238, 233, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 262, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 273, 274, 276] 

> @nonfluent_user_ids & @fluent_users_ids

TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
    from (irb):27:in `&'
```

Why isn't this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a typo (`@fluent_user_ids` vs `@fluent_users_ids`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland okay - will update. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that your second element in the comparison, `@fluent_user_ids`, is `nil`. Which is true as your array is named `@fluent_users_ids`. So it's just a typo, we have all been there !